# Reporting with cut and grep

Tags: bash, shell, grep, cut

I'm trying to create a script that gets an extension and reports in two columns, the user and the amount of files that user owns with that extension.
The results must be printed in report.txt

Here is my code.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Uncoment to create /tmp/test/ with 50 txt files
#mkdir /tmp/test/
#touch /tmp/test/arch{01..50}.txt

clear

usage(){
    echo "The script needs an extension to search"
    echo "$0 <extension>"
}

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    usage
    exit 1
fi

folder="/tmp/test/"
touch report.txt
count=0
pushd $folder

for file in $(ls -l); do
    grep "*.$1" | cut -d " " -f3 >> report.txt
done

popd
```

The program just runs endlessly. And I'm not even counting the files for each user.
How can I solve this using only grep and cut?

Comment: Can you give an input and expected output?

Comment: `grep "*.$1" | ...` greps ins stdin. There is your program waiting forever. I has no file argument or it is missing an input pipe.

Comment: you could replace the for loop with something like `find $folder -name "*.$1" -printf "%P\t%u\n" >> report.txt` and then some wc.

Comment: Why are you using `ls -l`? You'll end up grepping all the file attributes, not just the name.

Comment: How about just `ls *.$1 | wc -l`.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `stat` :

```
stat -c '%U' *."$1" | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2,"\t",$1}' > report.txt
```

As pointed out by mklement0, under BSD/OSX you must use a `-f` option with `stat` :

```
stat -f '%Su' *."$1" | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2,"\t",$1}' > report.txt
```

**Edit :**

To process many files and avoid argument number limitation, you'd better use a `printf` piped to the `stat` command (thanks again mklement0) :

```
printf '%s\0' *."$1" | xargs -0 stat -c '%U' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2,"\t",$1}'
```

Comment: Nicely done; to complement your GNU `stat` syntax with the one for BSD/OSX `stat`: `-c '%U'` must be replaced with `-f '%Su'`.

Comment: Good answer. Just one thing. Depending on the number of files the glob will reveal, the argument list for `stat` might get too long. A `find` based solution would be more stable.

Comment: @hek2mgl: It's a valid concern, but you could fix that with `printf '%s\0' *."$1" | xargs -0 stat ...` (since `printf` is a Bash _builtin_, it is not subject to the max. command-line length limitation).

Comment: it doesn't print anything on the file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop for this (unless you later need to loop over several folders), and changing the working directory in a script is rarely necessary. Also, reading `ls` output is usually not recommended.

Here's a version that replaces the loop, and uses `du`:

```
ext="$1"

printf "Folder '%s':\t" "$folder" >>report.txt

du -hc "$folder"/*."$ext" | sed -n '$p' >>report.txt
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the _count_ of files, not the combined storage size. Also, you're missing the grouping by owner username.

Comment: @mklement0 I interpreted "amount of files" as "the combined size of files". It is not exactly clear. I was also assuming that `$folder` later would be used to identify usernames (home directories).